# native directory unfound in CodenameOne

Tags: netbeans, codenameone, text-to-speech

I'm using the TTS just like in the DrSbaitso Demo in CodenameOne using Netbeans,
After creation the TTS.java interface
`import com.codename1.system.NativeInterface;

public interface TTS extends NativeInterface {
    public void say(String text);
}
`when I click on "Generate native Access" , I got the dialog "native interfaces generated : see the 'native'directory in the project. Unless i can't find the native directory in my project , and the compiler keep the error`java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mycompany.myapp.TTSImpl`. Any Idea ?

Answer (score 1):

The directory is under the project directory but NetBeans doesn't show it in the regular view only in the `Files` view.

You need to do a full "build" once and once you do that the project should find the impl class when running.

Comment: full build did not correct the problem for me.  Can't find class TTSImpl.

Comment: In the simulator? Device? If this is a problem in the simulator which IDE, how does the classpath in the IDE look? Notice that the simulator isn't a "big deal" as it would just run the JavaSE stubs, you should be able to handle that case correctly (where impl doesn't exist) by checking if the native interface instance is null.

Comment: When I implement TTSimpl, how do I resolve import android.speech.tts.TextToSpeech; in order to build to android?

Comment: The Android native build will compile that code under native Android environment where that package exists. Did you look at this video https://www.codenameone.com/how-do-i---access-native-device-functionality-invoke-native-interfaces.html